# What is the word to describe someone who gets up clumsily?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the proper verb to describe someone who gets up from his or her chair clumsily?

Comment: Perhaps **to groan** (out of a chair)? It's not currently in use, but it often accompanies any such movement.

Comment: A *clumsy* person. Perhaps *ungainly*.

Comment: I would perhaps say "he struggled to his feet".

Comment: He *stumbled* to his feet.

Answer (score 1):

As Ken Dodd once recalled in describing a drunken heckler in the audience of the Glasgow Empire, "He **uncoiled** himself as he got up from his seat". ('More boys who do comedy' Dawn French & Ken Dood - BBC4) This conjures up a picture in one's mind's eye of someone rising clumsily from his chair.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions like this. Word requests must explain the context they want to use a word in.